# How does the "d3fg" command work?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I would like to know how a "d3fg" command works in vi.

I have done some research on Google and found that `d` is delete and `fg` means foreground. Suppose, if we want to stop the session of vi and resume it afterwards, we can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to come out of the vi session. Then type `fg` to go back to the same vi session.

Now I wanted to know how this `d3fg` works in vi editor.

Comment: The best way to find out what a single command in Vim does, is not google, but the help system. Simply type `:h f` to get help on the `f` command.

Comment: @elyashiv not very useful when one thinks of the command as `fg`. What does `:he fg` give you?

Comment: @muru a lout of information - you find out there is no command `fg` (just `-fg`), so you conclude the command is f...

Answer (score 17):

In fact, `fg` is "foreground" in Bash, but not in Vi(m). `d3fg` means:

```
d - Delete until...
3 - Do the next motion 3 times
f - Go to the next occurrence of the next character pressed.
g - The character to go to.
```

Thus, `d3fg` will delete up to (including) the third letter `g` on the line after the cursor.

Thus the following text, with the cursor on the `0`:

> 01g2g3g4g5g6

Becomes after `d3fg`:

> 4g5g6