# How can I map d[count]d?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, count

*N.B. This is* not *a duplicate of [How does the "d3fg" command work?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/how-does-the-d3fg-command-work) Please read it before voting to close!*

I've come to a bit of an impasse in my [quest to get small deletions work like big ones](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/can-i-make-vim-also-save-small-deletions-into-register-1). The problem I've got is that I can't figure out how to remap commands like <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>. In fact, I can't even understand how they work in the first place, nor find any mention of them in Vim's help.*

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> is straightforward: it applies the `d` operator to the `3j` motion,

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> is also straightforward: it runs the `dd` command with a "count" of 3.

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> *looks* like it should be straightforward, it applies the `d` operator to the… but what is `3d`? It's not a motion. If you type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> on its own, Vim treats it as a count followed by an operator, and waits patiently for further input.

And you can't apply operators to other operators. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> isn't described in the help as a sequence of two operators. It's a separate, two-keystroke command. (cf. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, which does nothing.)

It also doesn't appear to be the case that the positioning of the count is flexible for commands that require two keystrokes: <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> moves the cursor down two screen-lines, but <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> discards the first two keypresses entirely and moves the cursor down one line.

So how does it work? Is this just a special case in Vim's internal code? Is there any way I can create a `d[count]d` mapping?

**EDIT**: Is it a text object? `:h text-objects` doesn't include it in the list of "text object selection commands", but then it *does* include dd in a list of deletions "grouped from small to big objects". And <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> does delete the word under the cursor and the following one. On the other hand, <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> does nothing.

<sub>* I'm sure some mention of them must exist, but I can't find it. I've read `:help deleting`, `:help motion.txt`, and tried `:helpgrep dNd` for all values of N from 1–9</sub>.

Comment: I think the last `d` acts as a confirm; So it's the same as `d3<CR>`. `y3y` and `c3c` also work the same ... I can't find any docs on this though in either the Vim :help, vi(1), nvi(1), or the POSIX spec... It does behave the same in `vi` and `nvi` btw.

Comment: In a way, `dd` is identical to `d_`. `_` brings the cursor to the first non-blank on the (`[count]`-1)th line down, but it's linewise, so when paired with an operator, it operates on entire lines. For that reason, it makes sense that a count can appear between the two `d`s.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Operator-pending mode

Between typing an operator (like `d`, `c`, or `gU`) and a motion (like `w`, `i}`, or `/foo<CR>`), Vim is in Operator-pending mode. You can create mappings for this using `:omap` and `:onoremap`.

In my examples, I'm going to map the Operator-pending `d` to `w`. This is a random choice, because I don't know what you actually wanted to use it for.

### Create an omap

Let's create a mapping for `d` in Operator pending mode. I'm gonna assume we're writing VimScript here (such as in your `.vimrc`), so I'll omit leading `:`s.

```
onoremap d w
```

This makes `dd` act like `dw`. It also makes `d[count]d` act like `d[count]w`. But I bet you didn't want to affect the behaviour of `dd` (i.e., no `[count]` supplied).

### Expression mappings

Expression mappings let you evaluate a VimScript expression to produce the right-hand-side of the mapping. The expression should evaluate to a string. Expression mappings are denoted by the `<expr>` keyword.

Vim also has some built-in variables that get populated at various times, and are often useful during mappings. One of them is `v:count`, which is the `[count]` supplied to an operator or motion.

Let's put that all together. If no `[count]` is supplied, `v:count` will be `0`. We can tell our mapping to just use `d` in that case.

```
onoremap <expr> d v:count == 0 ? 'd' : 'w'
```

Now `dd` behaves like the default (deletes a line), but `d[count]d` behaves like `d[count]w`. Cool!

### Restrict it to use after the `d` operator

You might notice something, though. Now `cd` also behaves like `cw`. This may not be a problem, but for completeness, let's restrict it so it only works after the `d` operator.

Vim has another variable, `v:operator`, which contains the operator most recently used. Let's check that, too, before doing anything special.

```
onoremap <expr> d (v:count == 0 \|\| v:operator != 'd') ? 'd' : 'w'
```

**NOTE:** Since `:map` commands can be chained with `|`, we have to escape them in our expression here. So the logical OR operator `||` becomes `\|\|`.

Cool, so `cd` and `c[count]d` are back to doing nothing, just like they used to. This is good so that other plugins can define `cd`.

### I don't want to just delete some other motion

If you wanted to map `d[count]d` to something totally different, nothing to do with deleting text, we can make that work too.

When you're typing commands in Normal mode, and you start typing a command by mistake, you can hit `<Esc>` to cancel that command. The same applies to your mappings.

Let's make `d[count]d` change the current line to whatever `[count]` is.

```
onoremap <expr> d (v:count == 0 \|\| v:operator != 'd') ? 'd' : '<Esc>cc' . v:count . '<Esc>'
```

The last part of the mapping is a VimScript expression: `<Esc>cc' . v:count . '<Esc>'`. That's `<Esc>` to cancel the pending `d` command, then `cc` to change the current line, `v:count` to type the value of the `[count]` (in Insert mode), and `<Esc>` to return to Normal mode. Note that we're building a string here using the VimScript concatenation operator, `.`.

---

Your actual use case is probably going to be different from what I've outlined here, but hopefully this helps you to get the ball rolling.

Happy Vimming!

Comment: Great answer! Upvoted. I did link to my use case (also on vi.SE) at the start of the question, but I guess you must have missed it. I basically need to do `:omap d d` (!), but unfortunately operator-pending mode is never actually reached because of my mapping for d that sets the custom operator function. Hopefully it's possible to tweak things to make `d3d` work how it should, though. (Let me know if you have any ideas, or feel free to post a complete solution to the other question if you prefer.) If I can't figure it out soon, I'll accept this and post another, more specific question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, I'm accepting this now. You explained both how to create such a mapping, and also how it works under the hood, which were the two things I asked.