# removing multiple lines - d3d vs 3dd

Tags: cursor-motions

I was speaking with my friend about removing multiple lines while using vim. They said they use **d3d** to remove 3 lines, whereas I use **3dd**

I understand my command is: 3 (repeat 3x) dd (delete the entire line)

And my friend's command is of the form ["x]d{motion} i.e. Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register x].

However, I don't think **3d** is a valid motion. Is it?
I found this page which is expessing the same confusions [how can i use dcountd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/how-can-i-map-dcountd) but it diverges into omaps and expression mappings which I am not interested in - I don’t want to change the behaviour I just want to understand it (and also find out where my friend would have found the command)

I don't understand why this **d3d** command works in vim.

Comment: The question title has a typo: 3d3 should be d3d.

Comment: for non-prime numbers, there's even an additional option- `2d2d = 4dd = d4d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page that you linked to is a useful read. Like you said, not all of it is relevant. What *is* relevant is the first sentence in [that answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2546/21495):

> Between typing an operator (like d, c, or gU) and a motion (like w, i}, or /foo), Vim is in Operator-pending mode.

In `dd`, after the initial `d`, vim is in operator-pending mode. Pressing `d` again is akin to the `_` motion. This is a *linewise* motion which moves the cursor to the start of the current line. Thus, the final `d` would mean "apply this operator (`d`) to the current line".

Now, in `d3d`, after the initial `d`, vim is, again, in operator-pending mode. In this mode, `3d` is likened to `3_`. Put together, `3d` would mean "apply this operator (`d`) for 3 lines."

tl;dr  `[count]d` is not valid in normal mode, but it *is* valid in operator-pending mode when the current operator is `d`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks as consistent behaviour among Vi clones. Consider the following excerpt from POSIX Vi spec.:

> **motion** An optional trailing argument used by the !, <, >, c, d, and y commands, which is used to indicate the region of text that shall be affected  by  the  command. **The motion can be either one of the command characters repeated** or one of several other vi commands (listed in the following table). Each of the applicable commands specifies the region of text matched  by  repeating  the  command; each command that can be used as a motion command specifies the region of text it affects.

So basically while you're typing `d` command, the next `d` is treated as "motion", and so both `d3d` and `3dd` shall be interpreted exactly the same. However, this is really rare input to see and to use.

Comment: This answer is completely valid but I can only mark 1 answer. Other answer makes the distinction that Motions in Normal and Operator-pending modes can be different which is the key piece of information I personally was missing.